# Solving Euler#1 through Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

So I want to solve the Project Euler Q1 through Javascript (because it's the only language I know-- I'm a beginner), and I don't know how to display the outcome of my code other than through HTML. I googled around and wrote this code combining HTML and Javascript, and ran it under the Brackets software, but nothing is showing up. Can someone help me?

```js
     /* If we list all the natural numbers below 10 that are multiples of 3 
    or 5, we get 3, 5, 6 and 9. The sum of these multiples is 23. Find the 
    sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000. */
    function math() {   
        var belowThousand = [];
        var sum = 0;
        for (var i=1; i<1000; i++) {
            if (i%3===0||i%5===0) {
                belowThousand.push(i);
                sum += i;
            }
        }
        console.log(sum);
    }
    
    math();
```

Comment: Once you get this sorted out, think about numbers that are divisible by both 3 and 5 (like 45).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see the results of

```
console.log()
```

you need to press "F12" in your browser and go to "console".

You can also do a

```
alert("TEXT");
```

and it will show as an alert.

Comment: I used alert(sum). Thank you for clarifying!